# Distorted string value in python selenium test with python 3

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

in my project we are using stripe for payments.
Payment form looks like this: https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/quickstart
We use the same test card nb value : 4242 4242 4242 4242 to test payments.
The problem is that sometimes selenium send keys:  4242 4242 4242 4224 ! 
I cant figure out whats going on, when running locally on browser, everything works fine.
Setup:
chromedriver 2.41 - Chrome headless mode 
Running tests on Travis,
Python 3.6
Selenium 3.12

Is the headless mode a problem? or iframe? or maybe something else.

```
stripe_form = WebDriverWait(driver, 120).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, '__privateStripeFrame3')))
driver.switch_to.frame(stripe_form)
fill_form_field(driver, 'cardnumber', '4242424242424242')
fill_form_field(driver, 'exp-date', '04 / 20')
fill_form_field(driver, 'cvc', '123')
fill_form_field(driver, 'postal', '12345')
driver.switch_to.default_content()

with wait_for_page_load(driver, timeout=120):
    driver.find_element_by_id('submitBtn').click()
```

Comment: I had similar problems with the send_keys() method... my workaround is to construct a while loop and delete and reenter the input until it is correct.
I also couldn't find out the issue. If you cannot extract the value because you do not want to save it you can select all, copy it to the cache and test if the cache value is equal to your data.

Comment: try send them in sequence Ex: sendKyes('4242); sendKeys('4242') ... etc. or input the whole string, do quick verify for input and what you have sent, if there is miss-match, clear(); sendKeys('full string')

Comment: thanks, will try to do that.. but im really curious what cause the problem.

Comment: Update the question with your code trials and the relevant HTML

Comment: You might have a problem in your script please show some code...

Comment: code added, pls check it